# Where do I find Mac installers?

Tags: 10.04, downloads, macbook, lynx

I can't seem to be able to find the MacBook Pro installer for Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx, which is what is recommended for my MacBook Pro 5,4 according to  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MactelSupportTeam/CommunityHelpPages.

I am using my Android phone to browse and download. D

Does that make any difference as to why I can't find a download option for this?

Comment: 10.04 was released in 2010 and is way too outdated now. Give 14.04 or 16.04 a try. Those are recent and stable.

Answer (score 3):

There's no "special" version of Ubuntu for Macs, at least not ones more recent than 2004. The very old ones do require a special version for PowerPC computers, but yours isn't that old, so you don't need to worry.

As for the recommended version, that guide is *way* out of date. 10.04 is from 2010 and has been EOL (end-of-life) for about a year (and it was only supported so long because it was a long-term-support release). You should be downloading 14.04 or 16.04. Just go to http://ubuntu.com and download from there.

It's also not really a good idea to download the image to your phone, because you're not going to be able to burn it to a DVD or flash drive from there. If you're using your phone to download because of internet connectivity, just transfer the download to your computer afterwards.

Ubuntu also doesn't have an installer, at least not anymore, in the way you're probably thinking. It is an installer, but it's a bootable installer and has to be burned to a flash drive or DVD to use. It isn't an EXE, DMG or PKG you can double-click and run, it's something you actually have to boot into as if it's its own OS.

Refer to these links for setting Ubuntu up:

[Creating a bootable DVD on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)

[Creating a bootable flash drive on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

[Creating a bootable DVD on Mac OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx)

[Creating a bootable flash drive on Mac OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)

Answer (score -2):

I found it I think, by using startpage searchengine to search for that version of installer for mac. The installer appears to be for both macs and pcs, and the reason im not sure is cuz both the alternate and initial options say, "choose this if unsure." 
I can only assume this download option contains both a pc exe installer and mac dmg in one...

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought it odd that the version would be so old, but im a newbie to all this.